# How do I index an array of jQuery objects elegantly?

Tags: jquery

I find myself starting to write this:

```
$($("a-selector-which-returns-multiple-objects")[index]).SomejQueryFunctionForExampleShow()
```

Because I have one query which returns multiple objects, then the `[index]` operator returns the DOM object, not a jQuery object, so I convert it back to a jQuery object with the outer `$()`.

This is working fine, but seems inelegant, and I feel I'm missing something about indexing into sets of jQuery objects - what's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to index your elements at all in the case you describe.  Because of the way JQuery chains its commands, any command you will be run on *all* the elements the previous selector returns.

The following example will hide all `<a>` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").hide();
});
```

If it needs to be a specific element, you should be giving it a unique ID to select:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-unique-id").hide();
});
```

If you want to return a specific index as a JQuery object, you should use the [eq function](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/eq#position).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").eq(0).hide();
});
```

But again, in your case, you don't need the index at all.

Comment: Thanks for this - eq() is what I was after.  An index is the easiest way to do this, because this is being called as part of a loop which is testing a bitmask that was returned from a piece of hardware.

Comment: I think you'd be able to use .each(function(i) { ... }); for that

Answer (score 2):

JQuery provides functions such as [Traversing/eq](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/eq) and [Traversing/slice](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice) for this purpose, as well as others like [Traversing/filter](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/filter) for more complex cases.

```
$("selector").eq(0).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute SomejQueryFunctionForExampleShow() on some of the object why index just do:

```
$("a-selector-which-returns-multiple-objects").SomejQueryFunctionForExampleShow().
```

Comment: The point about my [index] is that I only want to affect a single member of the multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [filter command](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/filter) to filter the original wrapped set and then perform a command on the sub set (and then return to the original wrapped set with [end command](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/end)).